# Am I a mezzo soprano?

Tags: voice, vocal-range

If my range is from G3-C6 with my tessiratura being from the A below middle C to the A below “high C” (C6), would I be considered a Mezzo Soprano?  My break from chest voice to mixed voice is at the E above middle C, and my break from mixed voice to head voice is at the F below high C. (C6)

Comment: *You* don't have a tessitura. Songs do. You have a *range*. How much will it help if your voice gets labelled? Serious question! Welcome to our site!

Comment: @Tim Is tessitura not used to describe comfortable/natural singing range for singers themselves?

Comment: @user45266 Yes, it is. Singers do have a tessitura. It's the range within their singing range where the voice sounds best.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, voice types aren't really ment to have such a fine definition, especially when based on range. In order to categorize a singer, I would listen to the sound of the voice, rather than to define their range. A mezzo-soprano usually has a deeper or fuller sound than a soprano.

I'm no expert on the subject, but I don't think labelling your voice based on your range will be very useful.